# Debugging Firebase circular reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

This is my cloud funcion code:

```
exports.BoughtHiLo = functions.database.ref('/buy/hilo/{uid}/').onWrite(event => {
 if (!event.data.exists()){return}
 const val = event.data.val()
 const userUID = event.params.uid
 const game = val.game
 const gemCost = hiLoInfo[game].gemCost
 const gamesRecieved = hiLoInfo[game].gamesRecieve
 return db.ref('/users/' + userUID + '/server/gems/').transaction(function(gems) {return (gems || 0) - gemCost}).then(function(gemsLeft) {
   const currentGems = gemsLeft.snapshot.val()
   promArr = []
   if (currentGems >= 0){
    promArr.push(db.ref('/users/' + userUID + '/server/hilogames/').transaction(function(hilogames) {return (hilogames || 0) + gamesRecieved}))
   }else{
    promArr.push(db.ref('/users/' + userUID + '/server/gems/').transaction(function(gemsUser) {return (gemsUser || 0) + gemCost}))
   }
   promArr.push(event.data.adminRef.remove())
   return Promise.all(promArr)
})
})
```

Everything works as expected (updating values), but later on when I look my console, I see this error:

> Error serializing return value: TypeError: Converting circular
>   structure to JSON

I looked around here for the error, I know I somewhere reference to a value to it self, but where in my code is it?? I can not debug it through Firebase, I have no idea what to do.

What is wrong with my code? Thanks.